# ES6 class getter function returns undefined in react after refresh

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

I am able to call the getter function. But upon refresh, the class is unable to find the getter function and returns undefined.

This is to save data into a class and then save the class into a state.
I have console logged the information and all the data appears present.

```
export class metaComparison {
    constructor(__key, __operator=null, __compareValue=null) {
        this._key     = __key;
        this._op      = __operator;
        this._compVal = __compareValue;
    }

    set key(__key)        { this._key     = __key; } 
    set operator(__op)    { this._op      = __op; }
    set compareVal(__val) { this._compVal = __val; }

    get key()        { console.log("key is: ", this._key); return this._key;}
    get operator()   { return this._op; }
    get compareVal() { return this._compVal;}

}
```

File 2:

```
import { metaComparison } from './meta-query-class'
.
.
.
this.setState(prevState => ({
 metaQueryConditional: [...prevState.metaQueryConditional, 
 new metaComparison(this.state.selectedMetaKey)]...
.
.
this.state.metaQueryConditional.map((singleQuery, idx) => {
return(
.
.
<h2> Metakey:  {singleQuery.key} {console.log("rendering single query which is", singleQuery, "and key is: ", singleQuery["_key"], singeQuery.key)}</h2>
```

Expected results is singleQuery.key returns the key value. The key value is returned. But upon refresh, I start getting undefined.

Comment: You do realize that Javascript is not persistent across page loads right? If that's what you want you'll have to use either url query params or the storage APIs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? I am using setState in React to set an array of the class instances. If I console log the state after refresh then all of my values that were set still exist, but the functions are undefined now. So im not sure why the data still exist but the functions dont

Comment: @Continuum, You said "If I console log the state after refresh then all of my values that were set still exist", that is a NO unless you have implemented a persistent storage. If you ONLY rely on React's state and when you refresh, the state will be re initialize. Please elaborate your question, give snippets if you have to.

Comment: My apologies I was confused by the phrasing. Yes, I have persistant storage as the react state is loaded from somewhere else. It appears that my question more relies on how to save a class instance as arrays. As it appears that the class instance is saved as an object and thus doesnt give me access to the functions anymore after refresh